# Android Huwaii Ascend P7-L10 P7-L10 image crop and save captured image issue

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I have implemented code for both image capturing and cropping functionality.
Same is working in Lenovo A536 and Huwaii Honor Holly but not working in Huwaii Ascend P7-L10. Even all of them have android 4.4.2 with Loilipop update.

1. First issue is that caputred image is not getting stored on the sd card while I have already provided permission for write access.
2. Second is I am not able to implement crop view in square form. It is adjustable by the end user while selecting image from gallery in only the phone above mentioned. My code is :

   ```
    public void selectGiniPicture(View view) {

       isGiniImageSelected = true;
       final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Picture", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WorkerRegActivity.this);
       builder.setTitle("Select Your Picture!");
       builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
               if (options[item].equals("Take Picture"))
               {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
               }
               else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
               {
                   Intent intent = new Intent();
                   //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                   intent.setType("image/*");
                   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                   intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                   //intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
                   //intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
                   intent.putExtra("outputX", 225);
                   intent.putExtra("outputY", 225);
                   intent.putExtra("scale", true);
                   intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
                   intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                       "Complete action using"), 2);
               }
               else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }
           }
       });
       builder.show();
   }
   ```

Perform Crop function for camera

```
    private void performCrop() {
    // take care of exceptions
            try {
                // call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
                // support it)
                Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                // indicate image type and Uri
                cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
                // set crop properties
                cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                // indicate aspect of desired crop
                //cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
                //cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
                // indicate output X and Y
                cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 225);
                cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 225);
                // retrieve data on return
                cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
                startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 6);
            }
            // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                Toast toast = Toast
                        .makeText(this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
```

OnActivityResult Function is as:

```
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                if (requestCode == 1)
                {
                    picUri = data.getData();
                    performCrop();
                }
                else if (requestCode == 2) {

                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    if (extras != null) {
                        Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                        capturedImage.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    } 
                }
    }
```

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are [many image cropping libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) available for Android. Please use one.

Comment: Okay thanks I got your idea to implement the lib but what about the camera